# $cordovaBarcodeScanner.encode fails silently on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have an Ionic Android/iOS application that should generate a barcode from any text the user enters. I'm using ngCordova's $cordovaBarcodeScanner for this part. The issue is that it works on iOS but not on Android:

```
$scope.changeCode = function () {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.encode(2048, $scope.content()).then(function(success) {
        debugger;
        console.log(success);
    }, function(fail) {
        debugger;
        console.log(fail);
    });
}
```

Neither the success nor the failure functions are ever called on Android. It's like the method call just disappears.

The other $cordovaBarcodeScanner function, .scan(), works perfectly fine across both platforms.

There is another thread on Stack Overflow similar to this one. The difference is that my app does not crash, it just acts like the encode function was never called.

I've tried replacing my barcodescanner.js with another version and I've tried adding permissions to the Android platform settings file.